# Inline стиль для vue js, которое изменяется

Tags: vue.js

```
 <tr v-for="(bid, ind) in bids">
                            <th>{{bid.numberOfOrders}}</th>
                            <th>{{total(ind)}}</th>
                            <th>{{bid.quantity}}</th>
                            <th style="position: relative">{{bid.price}}<div class="graphic" :style="width"></div></th>

                        </tr>
```

Как здесь прописать :style, которое числовым значением зависит от {{total(ind)}} метода?

Comment: [mcve] бы пригодился...

Comment: В каком смысле?

Comment: Ну и назовите же наконец `index` его законным именем :)) Откуда эта тяга к запутыванию кода :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужен реактивный style, то можно так:

```
:style="`width: ${total(ind)}px`"
```

[Или как тут в документации.](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-inline-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Comment: Спасибо. Работает) Но где вы взяли такой синтаксис?)

Comment: Хотя если это total(ind) функция в methods то не работает